# Why doesn't this regex pattern work?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to select commas without numbers of 4 digits or the word "id" before, I tried with this:

```
   ( ? < ! [ \ d { 5 } | id ] ) ,
```

**The problem**

for example, if input string is "1999," that comma is not selected, I don't understand why.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please provide examples of what do you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(?<!\d{5}|id),
```

Your pattern, `(?<![\d{5}|id]),` is looking for a comma that is not after a digit, `{`, `}`, `|`, `i`, or `d` - They should not be in a charterer class: `[]`. If anything, `(?<![\d]{5}|id),` will also work, but is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unless you're using the `/x` flag, each space will attempt to match a space. So take those out.

Second, you're using `[...]` presumably to group an alternation (`|`) but square brackets actually indicate a character class, *i.e.* `[\d{5}|id]` is equivalent to `[id5{}|]` and matches any *one* of those characters, but not more. What you mean is this:

```
(?<!\d{5}|id),
```

The final problem might be that many implementations of regex (you haven't specified which you're using) don't support variable-width lookbehind assertions. So, you may need to do something like:

```
(?<!\d{5}|...id),
```